# Questions about Video Settings

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Are questions allowed that ask what settings one should chose if one prefers quality or performance?

E.g. "When I want best quality, should I chose bilinear, triliniear or anisotropic texture filtering?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a post asking about what differences exist between certain video settings is definitely fair game. (If, perhaps, on the technical end of things)

It's certainly not much worse than [one of our more popular questions on the site.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25465/why-do-video-game-framerates-need-to-be-so-much-higher-than-tv-and-cinema-framer)

Just make sure not to write questions that boil down to "What graphics can my system support?" (Too localized), or "Which is the best texture filter?" (Not a Real Question).

Comment: I still think the linked question is off topic, and I'm really not comfortable with using that question as precedent.